# How to make a dll from a c++ project which utilizes other external dlls?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, dll

i have developed a c++ console application in opengl in which :
#1 utilizes a bunch of other dlls to run.
#2 consists of a bunch of classes all instantiated in one specific class called , Run_class with one method

what i have done to make the dll.proj build the dll : ( code snipet in the following )

- i added all the class directories to the main.cpp of the dll
- plus i added all the external dlls to the dll project as well .

  $(SolutionDir)/exLibs/GLM

### i want to make a dll from this method and call it in .net core.

in dll main.cpp file :

```
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\RUNCLASS.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\RUNCLASS.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Libs.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Shader.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Shader.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Camera.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Camera.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Model.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Model.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Texture.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Texture.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Window.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Window.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Light.h"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Light.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Mesh.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Mesh.cpp"

//C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Take_snapShot(const void* pbuffer, size_t plenght, std::vector<float> angoli, std::string output_path, float Increase_scale, bool _x_axis, bool _Y_axis, bool _Z_axis)
{

    RUNCLASS RC(pbuffer, plenght, angoli, output_path, Increase_scale, _x_axis, _Y_axis, _Z_axis);
    RC.snapshot_wih_loop_in_memory_output_path();
}
```

---

in .net core console app :

```
      [DllImport("C:\\Users\\pouya\\source\\repos\\Clonident\\Release\\Clonident_DLL.dll")]

        public static extern void Take_snapShot(System.String pbuffer, System.UInt32 plenght, Array angoli, string output_path, float Increase_scale, bool _x_axis, bool _Y_axis, bool _Z_axis);

 string filePath = @"C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Project_Theis\Models\MaxillaryPreScan.stl";

            byte[] my_file = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            // list 
            float[] lst_num = new float[5] { 10, 40, 200, 800, 890 };


            Take_snapShot(Encoding.Default.GetString(my_file), (uint)my_file.Length, lst_num, "_dll_tst.jpg", 10, true, true, true);
```

---

by building the c# app i get no error , so i consider the p/invoke works fine , but when i run the app i have the following error :

i have no clue what it means and what i should do about it .

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL
> 'C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Release\Clonident_DLL.dll' or
> one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.

---

Comment: its as it says your DLL is trying to link (dynamicaly or staticaly): `C:\Users\pouya\source\repos\Clonident\Release\Clonident_DLL.dll` file but it s not there or its not compatible (32/64 bit). SO you either use absolute paths somewhere or just did not copy all the needed DLLs you use to your project (where your executable is)

Comment: but as you can see i gave the full path in the dllImport tag

Comment: I do not use your environment so I am just guessing here however I would check these: 1. `C:\Users` folder can have access rights problems is your app running as admin and is your user folder with shared access? 2. is the DLL matching your executable (32/64 bit) 3. try to move your DLLs to where your exe is (regardless of your path and or use relative path) had problems with this in past that static DLL link ignores paths 4. are you sure the syntax for the path is correct (some functions want `//` some `\\ ` some `/` ... 5. is the problem in your DLL or in some subsequent one?

Comment: To check for that you can rename the DLL a little and see if the error message uses new name or the old one.

Comment: @PooyaSobhanipour, could you check the dependencies of your Clonident_DLL.dll? The possible exception reason may be that the Clonident_DLL.dll is in place, but some of it's dependencies could not be found. You can use dependency walker to check dll dependencies.